# RxJava zip operator does not emit events

Tags: rx-java

Have the following code:

```
final List<C1dbg> tmp_debug = new ArrayList<>();
Observable.zip(Observable.just(1), avgObs, C1dbg::aggr).subscribe(c1 -> tmp_debug.add(c1));

final List<Double> avg_debug = new ArrayList<>();
        avgObs.subscribe(avg -> {avg_debug.add(avg);});

...
public static C1dbg aggr( Object v, Double avg) {

            C1dbg r = new C1dbg();
            r.average = avg;

            return r;
        }
```

How it could be that avg_debug is filled with element after execution (i.e. avgObs emit an event) and tmp_debug is not?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it can't be. Can you provide a running example that compiles?

Comment: Add error handlers in the calls to `subscribe` to make sure you're not missing something.